# matplotlib Button not working when in nested GridSpec

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to use constrained_layout together with nested GridSpecs for placement of subplots and buttons. Here is a minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

def on_click(event):
    print("hey")

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[14, 1], figure=fig)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax1.text(0.5, 0.5, "ax1", va="center", ha="center")

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])

b = Button(ax2, 'hey')
b.on_clicked(on_click)

plt.show()
```

This works fine so far, the button changes color when hovering and the callback is executed on click, here is an image of the button working fine when created with axes from top-level GridSpec

[image]

Now, when I try to nest GridSpecs, i.e.

```
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
```

is replaced by

```
gs2 = gs[1, 0].subgridspec(1, 2)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs2[0, 1])
```

the layout is as desired,

[image]

but the button is not working (no color-change on hover, no reaction on click).

Tried `plt.sca(ax2)`, no change.
Interestingly, when I take out the `constrained_layout=True`, the button works.

Is this a bug, or what is going on here? Can someone please shed some light on this?

Please do not suggest using `tight_layout()` and/or `subplots_adjust()`. The above is only a minimal example, in real life I have a rather complex figure with many subplots and several buttons. To avoid overlapping labels etc. I need constrained_layout. tight_layout has limitations (e.g. does not consider all elements properly, like figure.suptitle()). constrained_layout together with nested GridSpec seemed to be a good solution, except the problem above.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Interestingly though, [this works fine](https://gist.github.com/ImportanceOfBeingErnest/846fc3da59520ad7589d970cb46ebebd).

Comment: Nice "hack" ;-). So axes need to be created all on the same "nesting level"?

Comment: Well, this is of course undesired, but a quick workaround. Ideally, it shouldn't matter which "level" they are in. Currently, I haven't found the cause, so I cannot tell anything more useful.

Comment: I created [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/16173) about it.

Comment: constrained_layout makes an invisible axes to take space even if you don't populate the SubplotSpec.  Unfortunately that grabs the muse event.  There will be a fix, but I think you can change the `zorder` of the axes as well to make it come out top

Comment: Thanks for creating the issue!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround setting the `zorder` puts the new axes above the "ghost" made by `constrained_layout`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

def on_click(event):
    print("hey")

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, figure=fig)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax1.text(0.5, 0.5, "ax1", va="center", ha="center")

gs2 = gs[1, 0].subgridspec(1, 2)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs2[0, 1])
ax2.set_zorder(10)
b = Button(ax2, 'hey')
b.on_clicked(on_click)

plt.show()
```